# Pyserial doesn't list my USB ports but just shows COM ports

Tags: python, pyserial

I have below code that I suppose that it lists information of ports on my PC.
My PC have 1 COM port and 10 USB 2.0 ports.
But when I execute, it just shows COM port information.

Here is my python code:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    print("hwid:", port.hwid)
    print("device:", port.device)
    print("name:", port.name)
    print("description:", port.description)
    print("pid:", port.pid)
    print("vid:", port.vid)
    print("serial_number:", port.serial_number)
    print("location:", port.location)
    print("manufacturer:", port.manufacturer)
    print("product:", port.product)
    print("interface:", port.interface)
```

Here is the result:

```
hwid: ACPI\PNP0501\1
device: COM1
name: None
description: Communications Port (COM1)
pid: None
vid: None
serial_number: None
location: None
manufacturer: (Standard port types)
product: None
interface: None
```

As you can see there is no USB devices listed.

What's your idea?

Comment: Why do you expect it to show USB ports? It should show any USB-to-serial devices that are connected to a USB port, but not general USB ports.

Comment: Then, will it appear in the list? Can you mention any documentation or ebook about it?

Comment: `pyserial` is a module for serial devices, not USB in general. As I said, it should show all serial devices on the PC (USB or COM), but it won't show general USB ports. A USB port is a connection that can appear as different kinds of devices depending on what is connected to it. If you need to see USB ports, you need something else. You haven't made it clear what you are trying to do or what exactly you need to see.

Comment: I want to read data from some electronic devices as data logger and show the result in form like what shows in oscilloscope.